# Fetch most recent records as part of Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I am joining 2 tables customer & profile. Both the tables are joined by a specific column cust_id. In profile table, I have more than 1 entry. I want to select the most recent entry by start_ts (column) when joining both the tables. As a result I would like 1 row - row from customer and most recent row from profile in the resultset. Is there a way to do this ORACLE SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use window functions:

```
select . . .
from customer c join
     (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cust_id order by start_ts desc) as seqnum
      from profile
     ) p
     on c.cust_id = p.cust_id and p.seqnum = 1;
```

You can use a `left join` if you like to get customers that don't have profiles as well.

Comment: @PunterVicky - If you work with Oracle, you might as well test Gordon's solution against others who use more than one join. Gordon's solution may prove much more efficient (faster). The reason you pay the big bucks for Oracle is exactly the extra things they have (that other SQL database products may not have), although analytic functions are pretty standard. Analytic functions were introduced with the specific purpose of reducing the number of time-consuming joins in our queries.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon & mathguy. I will try this out as well!

Answer (score 2):

One way (which works for all DB engines) is to join the tables you want to select data from and then join against the specific max-record of `profile` to filter out the data

```
select c.*, p.*
from customer c
join profile p on c.cust_id = p.cust_id
join
(
    select cust_id, max(start_ts) as maxts
    from profile
    group by cust_id
) p2 on p.cust_id = p2.cust_id and p.start_ts = p2.maxts
```

Comment: Thanks @juergen. I'll try this out.

Comment: "which works for all DB engines" may be a good thing, but it may also be a bad thing. If one spends the big dollars on Oracle products, they might as well take advantage of Oracle features that are not necessarily available in all DB engines. In this case, it is likely that analytic functions will provide a faster solution than repeated joins.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way (if there exists no newer entry then it's the newest):

```
select
   c.*,
   p.*
from
   customer c inner join
   profile p on p.cust_id = c.cust_id and not exists(
      select *
      from profile
      where cust_id = c.cust_id and start_ts > p.start_ts
   )
```